# Quicksort console crash with sorted array

Tags: c++, arrays, quicksort

I'm trying to make time complexity charts using QuickSort up to 50,000 numbers.
Sorting random numbers works fine. When sorting `already sorted` array over 4000 numbers I get `Debug\QS.exe (process 2208) exited with code -1073741571.`. It works fine with a median partition pivot.
The problem is probably around `Function uses '64000' bytes of stack: exceeds /analyze:stacksize '16000'. Consider moving some data to heap.`.

My knowledge is low so I solved the problem with regular arrays instead of usind std::array or vector.
Also for the quick sort I used pseudocode I was given. How should I implement the code to correct the "crash"?

EDIT: For generating an array in ascending order I firstly generated random array and then sorted it which I believe there are better approaches.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>

const int size = 50000;

std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<> num(1, 1000000);

void swap(int* a, int* b) {
    int t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t;
}

void generateAscending(int* arr, int size) {
    for (int index = 0; index < size; index++) {
        arr[index] = num(gen);
    }
    std::sort(arr, arr + size);
}


bool check(int* arr, int low, int high) {
    for (int i = low; i < high - 1; i++) {
        if (arr[i + 1] < arr[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}


int partition(int* arr, int low, int high) {
    int pe = arr[low];
    int l = low;
    int d = high;
    while (l < d) {
        while (arr[l] <= pe && l < high) l++;
        while (arr[d] >= pe && d > low) d--;

        if (l < d) {
            swap(&arr[l], &arr[d]);
        }
    }
    swap(&arr[low], &arr[d]);
    return d;
}

int partition_median(int* arr, int low, int high) {
    int m = low + (high - low) / 2; // median pivot
    int pe = arr[m];
    int l = low;
    int d = high;
    swap(&arr[low], &arr[m]);
    while (l < d) {

        while (arr[l] <= pe && l < high) l++;
        while (arr[d] >= pe && d > low) d--;

        if (l < d) {
            swap(&arr[l], &arr[d]);
        }
    }
    swap(&arr[low], &arr[d]);
    return d;
}

void quickSort(int* arr, int low, int high) {
    if (low < high) {
        int j = partition(arr, low, high);
        quickSort(arr, low, j - 1);
        quickSort(arr, j + 1, high);
    }
}

void quickSort_median(int* arr, int low, int high) {
    if (low < high) {
        int j = partition_median(arr, low, high);
        quickSort_median(arr, low, j - 1);
        quickSort_median(arr, j + 1, high);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int arr[size];

    generateAscending(arr, size);

    // Check if in ascending order
    if (check(arr, 0, size - 1)) {
        std::cout << "Array is in ascending order." << '\n';
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Array is not in ascending order." << '\n';
    }

    // Quick sort
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    quickSort(arr, 0, size - 1);
    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Time: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count() << " microseconds." << '\n';

    /*
    // Quick sort median
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    quickSort_median(arr, 0, size - 1);
    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Time: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count() << " microseconds." << '\n';            
    */

    if (check(arr, 0, size - 1)) {
        std::cout << "Array is in ascending order." << '\n';
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Array is not in ascending order." << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is a standard `qsort` function : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/qsort . Why can't you use the standard one?

Comment: @Renat The main idea is I understand what code does, basically learning the implementation process with the pseudo code given.

Comment: You're (a) sorting an already sorted sequence, and (b) always using the "left"-most element as your pivot eval, thus you're recursion will drive up to `size` calls deep. The divide-and-conquer is literally dividing into partitions of 1,(N-1) with each recursion. In short, you've picked the worst-case scenario to use a left or right-most pivot eval, and ran with it. Your program is literally hitting a stack overflow.

Comment: @WhozCraig Picking the worst case scenario `O(n^2)` is the main idea so I compare the charts. I'm trying to understand why the code runs fine using online compiler? Thank you for explaining.

Comment: It's not the N^2 that's faulting your code; that would just make it dog-ass slow. It's the N-recursive calls. That's all I'm saying. Btw, How to create a sorted sequence the lazy way: include `<numeric>` and use `std::iota(arr, arr+size, 1);`

Comment: @WhozCraig What would be a better approach?

Comment: Um... clearly using a median pivot is a better approach. As a general mantra, median-of-three is one of the more popular pivot selection mechanisms. To get past the recursion you could always stand up a manual stack and implement a non-recursive quicksort, passing in a pivot selection algorithm callable to test your different tests. At least they'd run and all be on the same playing field.